# Search in VSCode for the multiline contents of a set of XML tags, using a regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to do a global search of XML files.  Within those files there are multiple instances of these XML tags: `<translated></translated>`.  I need to find all occurrences of any hyphens `-` that exist anywhere between those tags, where the contents of those tags can be on multiple lines.

```
<translated>
    Content is here
    Could be on multiple lines
    The meeting could take 3-4 hours
</translated>
```

In the above example, the phrase "3-4 hours" has a hyphen in it.  I need a regex that works for VSCode which finds all incidences of hyphens which happen to be within a set of these XML tags.

Comment: maybe this extenstion https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akashsaluja.piped-regex-vscode

Comment: Not sure about Visual Code Studio (seems to have problems with multiline) but for pure regex, and to offer something to chew over consider: https://regex101.com/r/pTKG9B/1 if you need to capture/swap out the dash.  Otherwise maybe: https://regex101.com/r/pTKG9B/2 for just a match.  Do check this in another text editor to be sure if Visual Code studio is at fault.  VCS doesn't like it from what I can tell but xed (Linux, basic text editor) is happy with it.  Hmmm!

Comment: What are you going to do with the hyphens when you find them?  It helps to devise an answer to know.

Comment: Replace them with — (long dashes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1 (using VS Code)

**This only matches one dash at a time and not all dashes.**  This is because limiting the search to inside one set of tags means it can only do one pass at a time.  I was going to delete this answer but if it's the only answer given it may be better than nothing.  The work around would be that you would have to refresh the search (button above the search box) and click replace all over and over.  If there are lots of dashes this would be annoying but better than no answer.

---

I have been fiddling with Visual Code Studio and the following seems to work.

```
(<translated>(.|\n)*?)(-)((.|\n)*?<\/translated>)
```

Assuming you may be wanting to, for example, replace the dash it's possible to with adding back groups 1 and 4 wrapped around any new text...

```
$1 <yourTextHere> $4
```

### Example:

Before replace:

[image]

After replace (note only the `3-4` in the first section of the file(s) is affected and the `3 to 4` is not changed):

[image]

---

---

### Option 2 / Update (using Brackets.io)

While I'm unsure of the cause if the failure for VSCode to match across files, the following regex works with Brackets (google Brackets.io) across multiple files...

```
-(?=[^<]*?<\/translated>)
```

You have to have all your files in a folder and open the folder.  Then search in the project (`Find > Find in files`).  Notice in the screenshot it shows for the matches found across all files.  In the lower panel for the selected file `t2 copy.txt` it matches first on line 6 and then on line 16 and (correctly) does not match on line 10 because it is not contained in a translated tag set.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me.  VSC selects quite a lot of text rather than just the hyphens.

I did find a link to do multiline searches.  While inputting the search term, you have to hold down Ctrl while pressing Enter.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_multiline-search

Other than that I'm still kind of lost.

Comment: @vrtjason if you must use VSCode I don't have an answer for you.  I fiddled with Notepad++ and that seems happy but you have to have all the files open.  Atom editor doesn't seem to work.  VSCode (obviously) is having problems.  However, I tried Brackets and that works without opening lots of files - you just open a folder of the files and the regex `-(?=[^<]*?<\/translated>) ` works well from my test.  I've updated the answer with the option.  Sorry it's not VSCode but it's something.  Could be a bug or by design, or I'm not understanding something.  Whatever, it's stumped me.

Comment: Will try Brackets sometime tonight, thanks so much for your help on this.

Comment: Np.  Interesting problem (the sort of thing I'm always facing! :o).  The technically correct answer (perhaps) for changing XML/HTML is not to use regex - you'll see many answers on stack overflow saying not to use it (the world will end if you do).  Hence it's better to use a proper HTML/XML parser and code a solution.  However, I find you can stretch regex to fix markup but it does have its limits - even without this weirdness between editors.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey, `-(?=[^<]*?<\/translated>)` does work in Brackets! Although I couldn't use the regex in the original answer, this is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Glad it helps. Even if it takes a different editor. :0)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `-(?=[^<]*?<\/translated>)` doesn't work in vscode is because it does not EXPLICITLY contain a newline `\n`.  Even though `[^<]` includes newlines, the `\n` needs to be actually written into the regex in order to trigger the multiline option.  Why is this?

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75265 which uses a similar regex. The issue makes for interesting reading ;>}  Primarily for performance reasons.

So simply using this

`-(?=[^<]*?\n*<\/translated>)`

works in vscode!

---

`-(?=[^<]*?\n<\/translated>)`  would work for you too unless you have single line blocks like:

```
<translated>Con-tent is he-re</translated>
```